# How could Adrian Bejan's 'Constructal Law' be formulated mathematically?

Tags: mathematical-physics, flow, non-linear-systems

Adrian Bejan is known for having devised a very interesting theory for the hierarchical and aesthetic structure found in nature, from the branching tree shape of river deltas to the tree shape of bronchioles in the lungs.

[image: River & Tree originally from Unsplash]

- Relevant paper: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2871904/.
- Short YouTube interview and explanation: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lLAYHnJVmjE&feature=emb_title

As I am cognisant of my own weaknesses as a mathematician I thought I would pose the question to Mathematics Stack Exchange requesting a relatively tractable mathematical explanation of this theory, perhaps with code examples.  **Please would you provide a relatively simple mathematical formulation of the constructal theory - perhaps with a numeric example or code - which is stated as:**

> “for a finite-size flow system to persist in time (to live) it must
> evolve such that it provides greater and greater access to the
> currents that flow through it”

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.